# Rename various folders ignoring current name with Better Finder Rename

Tags: macos, applications, folders, utilities, automation

I have the following folders

```
trip to xxx
folder-temp
pic-temp
my-xxx-videos
```

I wanna rename all the folders to "my-folders1", "my-folders2" and so on.

I am using better finder rename but I don't see an option that lets me completely remove any folder name and replace it with something else. Any ideas?

I already know how the incrementing number work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can 'completely remove any folder name and replace it with something else' using the **Completely rename** action, available from Advanced & Special:

> This feature simply renames a file to the new name specified above. This is useful in combination with the droplet feature.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Maybe it's easier to open Terminal, go the the parent folder and run

```
i=0
for f in *; do
    if [[ -d "$f" ]]; then
        mv "$f" my-folders$i
        ((i=i+1))
    fi
done
```